# Type 'UIApplication' has no member 'didBecomeActiveNotification'

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication, notificationcenter

I'm trying to add observer for `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` with following code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in /* some code */ }
```

but Xcode says `Type 'UIApplication' has no member 'didBecomeActiveNotification'` despite it's [officially documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622953-didbecomeactivenotification) as `UIApplication` class constant. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It depends on the SDK you are using. In the documentation you have to [Show the API changes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622953-didbecomeactivenotification?changes=latest_minor)

Comment: @vadian - FYI: I think Apple changed the pages so they don't show the API changes anymore.

Comment: @benc I know, the API changes are displayed after a WWDC when a new SDK is introduced.

Comment: Do not forget to: import UIKit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change notification name to `.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in /* some code */ }
```

Apparently, `didBecomeActiveNotification` works for iOS 12 SDK only.

Answer (score 14):

When you are using Xcode 10, in **Build Settings**, if you set **Swift Language Version** to be `Swift 4`, you should write:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in /* some code */ }
```

If it is set to be `Swift 4.2`, use this instead:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in /* some code */ }
```